# Can solidity manage and process blob,clob or xml objects?

Tags: solidity

Understand that one should limit blockchain only to transactions information that needs to be decentralised and not file storage related objects. However, if one needs to process some xml objects before putting it on the blockchain, how should one do it? In the dapp tier itself?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of functionality is not offered by default in Solidity.

However there are some external API that might help you do achieve your needs. Depending on the application that you're trying to build you can either choose to use [Oraclize](https://docs.oraclize.it/#general-concepts-parsing-helpers) and invoke external services to parse XML, JSON and the other supported formats or you can build the parsing process in your DApp and send the data already parsed to the contract (or use a dedicated backend for this task depending on what you need to do).

In the first case the Oraclieze service helps you to make your app easier, but, at the same time, you [need to pay](https://docs.oraclize.it/#pricing) for the provided service.

In the second case you need to write the components on your own increasing the complexity of your app.